# Bridge Table Error in SQL Fiddle

Tags: sql, sql-server, bridge, sqlfiddle

I get the following error in Sql Fiddle:

```
Schema Creation Failed: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'.:
```

The following are my `CREATE TABLE` scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(
      UserName_ID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      Password    varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      F_Name      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      L_Name      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      Email       varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT Employees_PK  PRIMARY KEY(UserName_ID));

    CREATE TABLE Training_Sessions (
        Session_ID          int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL ,
        Session_Name        varchar(255)       NOT NULL,
        Session_Description varchar(255)       NOT NULL,
        Session_Date        varchar(255)       NOT NULL,
        Organizer           varchar(255)       NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT Training_Sessions_PK        PRIMARY KEY(Session_ID));

    CREATE TABLE Enrolled
    (
        UserName_ID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        Session_ID  int          NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_Enrolled   PRIMARY KEY
        (
            UserName_ID,
            Session_ID
        )
        FOREIGN KEY (UserName_ID) REFERENCES Employees(UserName_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY (Session_ID)  REFERENCES Training_Sessions(Session_ID);
    )
```

I'm working on a project in which DB is not set up on server yet and trying to get some scripts out of the way.  According to http://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/understanding-a-sql-junction-table/ my syntax is correct for SQL Server

Comment: You put a semicolon in a wrong place, and also forgot to put a comma after the constraint ([link to sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8360d)). Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(
  UserName_ID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  Password    varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  F_Name      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  L_Name      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  Email       varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT Employees_PK  PRIMARY KEY(UserName_ID));

CREATE TABLE Training_Sessions (
    Session_ID          int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL ,
    Session_Name        varchar(255)       NOT NULL,
    Session_Description varchar(255)       NOT NULL,
    Session_Date        varchar(255)       NOT NULL,
    Organizer           varchar(255)       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Training_Sessions_PK        PRIMARY KEY(Session_ID));

CREATE TABLE Enrolled
(
    UserName_ID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Session_ID  int          NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Enrolled   PRIMARY KEY
    (
        UserName_ID,
        Session_ID
    ),
    CONSTRAINT user_fk FOREIGN KEY (UserName_ID) REFERENCES Employees(UserName_ID),
    CONSTRAINT sess_fk FOREIGN KEY (Session_ID)  REFERENCES Training_Sessions(Session_ID)
);
```